# AWS API Gateway with Lambda proxy always produces base64 string response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using API Gateway Lambda proxy integration and trying to return a binary `application/protobuf` response.  No matter what I do, the response body is always a base64 encoded string

- I have `application/protobuf` setup as a `binary media types` in APIG
- My client (javascript) is sending following headers in the `POST`:

  `Accept: application/protobuf 
  Content-Type: application/protobuf`
- My lambda is responing with `content-type: application/protobuf`, and correctly setting the `IsBase64Encoded` Lambda response to `true`

How do you get APIG to base64 decode the string? I swear I had this working a few months ago when I 1st tried this.

Note: I've also tried `*/*` as a `binary media types`

Some related posts to add background:

- https://github.com/twitchtv/twirp/issues/81
- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/issues/39#issuecomment-276019222

**Update:**

Turns out I can only get it working if `binary media type` is set to `*/*`.  The client `Accept` header has no impact once it is set to this.

Many bad side effects of using `*/*` because every response is attempted to get decoded (even when IsBase64Encoded is false or not set)

I thought it wasn't decoding because Chrome network inspect tools will always show binary data as base64 encoded in the `Preview` tab.  You can see the protobuf in the `Response` tab.

Comment: You mentioned "many bad side effects of using */*", but I don't see them. Can you help me understand how to observe these side effects. I have a simple repo at https://github.com/activescott/apig-lambda-proxy-binary-response that demonstrates this but I'm not seeing any side-effects (e.g. on the html function response for example).

Comment: I have to admit, I didn't test the `*/*` on responses that were not binary.  I was just making an educated guess that if APIG was configured to this, it would try to base64 decode EVERY response.  Now that you mention this, I'm wondering if APIG only does the decode if `IsBase64Encoded` is true.  However that doesn't make sense in my head. If this were the case why the need for APIG `binary media type` in the 1st place.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm trying to reason through the same things here :) And I have to admit, I'm unclear on the need/purpose of needing both `isBase64Encoded` _and_  `binaryMediaTypes`. I'll probably keep tinkering and update that repo with more details as I confirm them...

Comment: In case anyone might find it helpful, I have dedicated a repo at https://github.com/activescott/apigateway-lambda-binary-response to documenting and demonstrating the various details of binary responses with Amazon API Gateway + AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem was I'm using CloudFront in front of API Gateway, and I was not passing the `Accept` header to the origin (APIG).

The docs on handling binary with Lambda proxy are not great, so here is a quick summary:

- Your client must send an `Accept` header who's [1st media type matches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-workflow.html) what you have set as a `binary media types` in API Gateway
- Your Lambda, if serving a binary media type, must set `IsBase64Encoded` to true AND the `body` must be base64 encoded

If the clients `Accept` header matches an entry in API Gateway's `binary media types` and these conditions are met, API Gateway will transform (base64 decode) before sending a response to the client.

[This blog post](https://github.com/rynop/twirpl) walks you through step-by-step on how to get it working (without CloudFront).

[This](https://github.com/rynop/abp-single-lambda-api) is a full blown [aws-blueprint](https://github.com/rynop/aws-blueprint) for getting a production grade ci/cd with CloudFront.

Comment: what if you don't have access to set request headers like in calling from a browser?